# how to create dynamic element reference name angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to create element reference in for loop in template

```
<input type="text" #name />
```

I mean `#name`, I want to create it in a loop:

```
<input type="text" #name1 />
<input type="text" #name2 />
```

Is there is a way to create it?